# Why jQuery keyup is not working while I try to build keyboard shortcut on my website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, accessibility, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to build keyboard shortcuts for accessibility in my website. For example, when user presses '1' I want to move him to the home. When user presses '2', to a different page.

I'm trying to use keyup for this but it's not working.

```
$(function() {
  $(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 1) {
      console.log('1');
      window.location.href = '/';
    } else if (e.which == 2) {
      window.location.href = '/escolas';
    } else if (e.which == 3) {
      window.location.href = '/noticias';
    } else if (e.which == 4) {
      window.location.href = '/eventos';
    } else if (e.which == 5) {
      window.location.href = '/contato';
    }
  });
});
```

Can someone help me? It's not logging 1 when I press '1'.

Comment: Please refer >http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/javascript-handling-keyboard-shortcuts-with-jquery-key-catch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the key character by `String.fromCharCode(event.which);`, and then directly compare with actual character:

```
 $(function() {
      $(document).keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.key) {
           var key = e.key;
         } else { 
           var key  = String.fromCharCode(e.which || e.keyCode);
         }
        if (key == 1) {
          console.log('1');
          window.location.href = '/';
        } else if (key == 2) {
          window.location.href = '/escolas';
        } else if (key == 3) {
          window.location.href = '/noticias';
        } else if (key == 4) {
          window.location.href = '/eventos';
        } else if (key == 5) {
          window.location.href = '/contato';
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: Remember this is not going to work if the user presses any of these numbers using the numpad.

Comment: @CristianoSoares, Thanks for the point, Now its working for numpad too.

Answer (score 4):

It is because the key code for '1' is not 1 but 49 (or 97 for the one on the numpad).

Check this to see your key code:

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).keyup(function(e) {
    $('body').text(e.type + ' ' + e.which);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using wrong keycodes. Refer [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/)

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 49) {
      console.log('1');
      window.location.href = '/';
    } else if (e.which == 50) {
      window.location.href = '/escolas';
    } else if (e.which == 51) {
      window.location.href = '/noticias';
    } else if (e.which == 52) {
      window.location.href = '/eventos';
    } else if (e.which == 53) {
      window.location.href = '/contato';
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**e.which** gives you ASCII value. To convert ASCII into character use **String.fromCharCode(e.which)**.

```
$(function () {
    $(document).keyup(function (e) {            
        if (String.fromCharCode(e.which) == 1) {
            window.location.href = '/';
        } else if (String.fromCharCode(e.which) == 2) {
            window.location.href = '/escolas';
        } else if (String.fromCharCode(e.which) == 3) {
            window.location.href = '/noticias';
        } else if (String.fromCharCode(e.which) == 4) {
            window.location.href = '/eventos';
        } else if (String.fromCharCode(e.which) == 5) {
            window.location.href = '/contato';
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna go fancy:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    'use strict';
  
    const addresses = [
      {
        codes: [49, 97],
        path: '/'
      },
      {
        codes: [50, 98],
        path: '/escolas'
      },
      {
        codes: [51, 99],
        path: '/noticias'
      },
      {
        codes: [52, 100],
        path: '/eventos'
      },
      {
        codes: [52, 101],
        path: '/contato'
      }
    ]
    $(document).on("keyup", evt => {
      const key =  evt.which;
      addresses.map(address => {
        if(address.codes.filter(code => code === key).length)
          window.location.href = address.path;
      })
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```